# How fill tables from database with initial values through Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my spring project, i am using Hibernate to export my entity classes to a previously created database. But I want that, besides the entities/tables, some initial values should be created in the database. Anyone can point a direction of how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your insert sqls in a file called `import.sql` in the class path. Once when a SessionFactory is created it would execute this insert script and import all these data.

For example in maven project it would be under \src\main\resources\import.sql

If your import file name is different, you can set it using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property and give your file name.